# Permutations and Decision Trees with R

Tags: r, permutation, igraph, decision-tree

I was wondering if there is a way to produce a decision tree that solves a permutation of selecting n objects of k classes. We have the set **A={1,2,...,10}**, and the subsets **B={1,2,..,5}, C={6,7}** and **D={8,9,10}**. The total number of permutations can be calculated by

```
x <- factorial(10)/(factorial(5)*factorial(2)*factorial(3))
```

I would like to produce a decision tree similar to an edge list, as the following:

```
1   2   5   B
1   3   2   C
1   4   3   D
2   5   4   B
2   6   2   C
2   7   3   D
3   8   5   B
3   9   1   C
3   10  3   D
4   11  5   B
4   12  2   C
4   13  2   D
5   14  3   B
5   15  2   C
5   16  3   D
6   17  4   B
6   18  1   C
6   19  3   D
7   20  4   B
7   21  2   C
7   22  2   D
8   23  4   B
8   24  1   C
8   25  3   D
9   26  5   B
9   27  3   D
10  28  5   B
10  29  1   C
10  30  2   D
11  31  4   B
11  32  2   C
11  33  2   D
12  34  5   B
12  35  1   C
12  36  2   D
13  37  5   B
13  38  2   C
13  39  1   D
14  40  2   B
14  41  2   C
14  42  3   D
15  43  3   B
15  44  1   C
15  45  3   D
16  46  3   B
16  47  2   C
16  48  2   D
17  49  3   B
17  50  1   C
17  51  3   D
18  52  4   B
18  53  3   D
19  54  4   B
19  55  1   C
19  56  2   D
20  57  3   B
20  58  2   C
20  59  2   D
21  60  4   B
21  61  1   C
21  62  2   D
22  63  4   B
22  64  2   C
22  65  1   D
23  66  3   B
23  67  1   C
23  68  3   D
24  69  4   B
24  70  3   D
25  71  4   B
25  72  1   C
25  73  2   D
26  74  4   B
26  75  3   D
27  76  5   B
27  77  2   D
28  78  4   B
28  79  1   C
28  80  2   D
29  81  5   B
29  82  2   D
30  83  5   B
30  84  1   C
30  85  1   D
31  86  3   B
31  87  2   C
31  88  2   D
32  89  4   B
32  90  1   C
32  91  2   D
33  92  4   B
33  93  2   C
33  94  1   D
34  95  4   B
34  96  1   C
34  97  2   D
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
.   .   .   .
```

The first two columns correspond to the edge list, the third column is the number of elements in each subset decreasing by each ramification and the fourth column is just the subset name.

One computed the edge list, I'm thinking on plotting the graph with this command:

```
plot(g, layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g, root=1)
```